# How to create a input field for formatted reply and get output as input in mysql and php

Tags: php, html, mysql, wysiwyg, code-formatting

I am making a forum where someone requires to reply with their answer. From HTML `<textarea>` input the reply is limited with `<pre>` tag. Everyone doesn't know how to make a heading with tags or some styling.

I am working with PHP and MySQL and beginner with this system. Is there any way to input text with simple formatting where styling may be possible by icon clicks and reply sends in MySQL.

Comment: there are many wysiwyg editors available: https://www.tinymce.com/ https://quilljs.com/ https://ckeditor.com/ to name a few.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me, but search for `WYSIWYG editor` and maybe you get some ideas.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've tried with tinymce. And its awesome.